# Photographs of people with their eyes closed leads to a faster-than-light device

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a (mildly humorous) short "story" I probably read in the 1980s; I recall it being more of a report than an actual story with a plot.

Some scientist is intrigued by the fact that people so often have their eyes closed in flash pictures, and discovers that eyelashes can detect a flash before the light from it actually reaches the eye.  From this somehow a FTL device is constructed.  (I don't recall if it was a space drive or an ansible.)

Comment: I know I read this one many years ago.  Probably in Analog or Asimov's.  I think the resulting tech was called something like the Maybelline Drive.  I'd be surprised if it was more than a page or two in length.

Comment: Or maybe it was the Revlon drive.

Comment: Then again, maybe it's Maybelline

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is "[QTL](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2193350)" by Arlan Andrews, published as *Analog*'s "Probability Zero" column for February 1987.

> "It was the term, *faster than C*, that finally revealed to me, in a flash," the physiologist said, "that there were phenomena quicker than light."
>
> "*Quicker* than light?" the question sputtered incoherently out of the physicist's mouth.  "What do you mean *quicker?*"

Eyes shut in photographs:

> "Simple-we've all photographed our family and friends, and invariably the subject will have his or her eyes shut.  How can this be?"

Eyelashes can pre-detect the flash:

> We believe eyelashes act as antennae that discriminate among the ethereal vibrations, reacting to previously unsuspected precursors of light waves that travel ahead of the light wavefront

From which comes a space drive:

> "And so, children," the Historian said, "we have the story of the development of the QTL drive that powers our so-called 'shadow ships' as they wink across the Galaxies

I can't quote any more, the article is scarcely more than a page all told.  Hat tip to Dosco Jones for his clue (it *is* "Revlon Drive") from which I was able to find this.

Comment: Fun side note: that implies that eyelids can achieve a speed of at least 0.005c.